Formal connection between fully homomorphic encryption schemes and field homomorphism
In fully homomorphic encryptions schemes (FHE), we aim to preserve both additional and multiplication operations in the encrypted space such that the operations can be decrypted later. This concept seems similar to field homomorphism in mathematics, which also deals with preserving addition and multiplication.
I would like to know if FHE schemes and field homomorphism are formally connected, or even stronger equivalent. Specifically, are all FHE schemes instances of field homomorphisms? or are FHE schemes closer to the idea of field isomorphism?
While the main focus of my question is on the connection between field homomorphism and FHE, I would also appreciate generalized answers that extend to additive, multiplicative, or other types of homomorphic encryption schemes.

Although they are similar, the field homomorphism in mathematics is done when the homomorphism is constructed explicitly. On the other hand, the (somewhat) FHEs problems start when we build the two operations. We cannot execute an arbitrary number of operations on the encrypted domain and then return to the plaintext domain.  The noise growth is the main issue to deal with. Now, for the last part, start from Wikipedia's FHE page to see partial and other FHE schemes.
